# How Does Apple do the UIButton Highlight Effect in the Calculator App?

Tags: ios, swift

In the iOS Calculator app, when you slide your finger through all the buttons, theres some sort of highlight effect as you touch the button and let go.

Anyone know how apple does that?

Comment: Use UITapGesture?

Comment: I think this is a good question, but just needs more context. I don't understand the votes to close it or the downvotes. Try the Calculator iOS app, and you can scroll through the buttons and they indeed get highlighted.

Comment: @Glenn I'll make another question, I should've added more details

Comment: If you make another question please remember to remove this one. Also please read these to help you with your next question: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example SO is a place to ask for help debugging code not for asking open ended questions about how to do something. You should make an attempt yourself and post your code for help with the problems you encounter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The calculator keys (circles with numbers in them) are just drawings, not buttons.  The only view is the background. It uses just ordinary UIResponder touch methods `touchesBegan`, `touchesMoved`, `touchesEnded`. Using those methods, the view just watches to see where the touch is, relative to the circle drawings, and responds by redrawing accordingly.